# Flex remote object performance

Tags: apache-flex, remoteobject

Our flex client needs to invoke server side EJB3 session bean. For each module we have seperate session bean.

Whether it is best to have separate flex end point (remote object) to each session bean to invoke methods or to create a single facade session bean as an endpoint and invoke other session bean methods through this facade bean.

Whether creating multiple flex end points increases the performance or its an expensive process?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a RemoteObject is not an expensive process but having many of them won't really increase client-side performance either. Typically all of your RemoteObjects will reference a shared ChannelSet which basically represents the connection to the server endpoint.  I would recommend using one RemoteObject for each session bean you have. You can relate a RemoteObject to a session bean by specifying the "destination" property on the RemoteObject and ensuring that your server side implementation of the FlexFactory interface resolves the destination name to the appropriate session bean.